# SQL 2005 - Split string into sections and return values from within split sections

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm not sure if I'm phrasing this in the best way but I have a large text string (ntext format) which is currently not indexed (I am looking into getting a full text index but I'm not going to be able to for a while at least) which is in an audit table detailing changes to data in other tables.

What I am trying to do is to pull out the old and new value for a specific table and field name, for example for this row:

```
CREATE TABLE #example
(
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER --unique audit id
,date_created DATETIME --date data was modified
,changes NTEXT --what parts of the data have been changed
)

INSERT INTO #example VALUES ('74158983-7123-4AC8-A16A-CF88D3115B86','2006-04-05 13:30:42.993','<ChangedAttributes><Attribute><Name>Table1</Name><Field>field1</Field><Value>15980ffc-209f-46bb-8d15-31100640b5a8</value><OldValue>15980ffc-209f-46bb-8d15-31100640b5a8</OldValue></Attribute><Attribute><Name>Table2</Name><Field>field1 </Field><Value>05/04/2006</Value><OldValue </Attribute><Attribute><Name>Table2</Name><Field>Field2</Field><Value>Apple</Value><OldValue>Orange</OldValue</Attribute></ChangedAttributes>')
```

(which is how my data appears in the reference table) 
I would like to pull the old and new values for table 1 and field 1 ONLY, giving the following output:

```
CREATE TABLE #output
(
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER --unique audit id
,date_created DATETIME --date data modified
,old_value VARCHAR(255) --what the data value was
,new_value VARCHAR(255) --what the data value was changed to
)
INSERT INTO #output VALUES('74158983-7123-4AC8-A16A-CF88D3115B86','2006-04-05 13:30:42.993','15980ffc-209f-46bb-8d15-31100640b5a8','193B3612-551D-4EB0-B840-900F916A1BF7')
```

As I say, that may sound like gibberish so if there's anything I can do to clarify I'll do my best!

Thanks :)

Comment: The xml in changes is invalid. Is that a mistake in this case or do you need to be able to handle invalid xml data in changes?

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with the XML in this case? I'm not familiar with it so not sure if it's my error or it's something wrong with the data

Comment: First `<Value>` tag is closed with a tag `</value>`. XML is case sensitive. `<OldValue` in second attribute has no close tag. Should be `<OldValue/>`. <OldValue> in last attribute tag is missing a `>` after the closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that works if the xml is correct.

```
declare @T table (id uniqueidentifier, date_created datetime, [changes] ntext)

insert into @T values (
  '74158983-7123-4AC8-A16A-CF88D3115B86',
  '2006-04-05 13:30:42.993',
  '<ChangedAttributes>
    <Attribute>
        <Name>Table1</Name>
        <Field>field1</Field>
        <Value>15980ffc-209f-46bb-8d15-31100640b5a7</Value>
        <OldValue>15980ffc-209f-46bb-8d15-31100640b5a8</OldValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name>Table2</Name>
        <Field>field1 </Field>
        <Value>05/04/2006</Value>
        <OldValue/>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name>Table2</Name>
        <Field>Field2</Field>
        <Value>Apple</Value>
        <OldValue>Orange</OldValue>
    </Attribute>
</ChangedAttributes>')


select
  id,
  date_created,
  c.a.value('OldValue[1]', 'varchar(50)') as old_value,
  c.a.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(50)') as new_value
from
    (select id, date_created, cast([changes] as xml) as [changes]
     from @T) as T
cross apply
   [changes].nodes('ChangedAttributes/Attribute') c(a)
```

Result

```
id                                   date_created            old_value                            new_value
74158983-7123-4AC8-A16A-CF88D3115B86 2006-04-05 13:30:42.993 15980ffc-209f-46bb-8d15-31100640b5a8 15980ffc-209f-46bb-8d15-31100640b5a7
74158983-7123-4AC8-A16A-CF88D3115B86 2006-04-05 13:30:42.993                                      05/04/2006
74158983-7123-4AC8-A16A-CF88D3115B86 2006-04-05 13:30:42.993 Orange                               Apple
```

**Edit 1**
This will give you the first Attribute in the xml

```
select
  id,
  date_created,
  c.a.value('OldValue[1]', 'varchar(50)') as old_value,
  c.a.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(50)') as new_value
from
    (select id, date_created, cast([changes] as xml) as [changes]
     from @T) as T
cross apply
   [changes].nodes('ChangedAttributes/Attribute[1]') c(a)
```

**Edit 2** With filter on name instead

```
select
  id,
  date_created,
  c.a.value('OldValue[1]', 'varchar(50)') as old_value,
  c.a.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(50)') as new_value
from
    (select id, date_created, cast([changes] as xml) as [changes]
     from @T) as T
cross apply
   [changes].nodes('ChangedAttributes/Attribute') c(a)
where c.a.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'Table1'
```

**Edit 3** Using substring instaed. Will work on your "xml"

```
select 
  id,
  date_created,
  substring([changes], charindex('<OldValue>', [changes], 0)+10, charindex('</OldValue>', [changes], 0)-charindex('<OldValue>', [changes], 0)-10) as old_value,
  substring([changes], charindex('<Value>', [changes], 0)+7, charindex('</value>', [changes], 0)-charindex('<Value>', [changes], 0)-7) as new_value
from @T
```

Comment: This looks very impressive - is there any way of bulding in the table name so that I can filter on this - in this example I am only interested in the top row of the result set (the data for table1, field1)

Comment: Added query to get first row (Attribute) in xml. No big change :)

Comment: And one version with filter on name=table1

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm presuming that actually my data is not valid XML as when I apply this I get: Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 82, illegal name character Msg 6304, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: An unexpected error has occurred in the MS-XML parser :(

Comment: Added comment to Question about what is missing in XML

Comment: Fantastic - with a minor tweak it works amazingly well :) I only wish I could give you more rep!